# Checkin to VSTS using TF.EXE without interactive login service account

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc, tf-cli

I am using TF.exe command line utility to check-in to TFS once my build finishes on TeamCity.

Build step is using command line. TeamCity build is running under service account from domain. service account's interactive login is disabled.

When I using tf.exe it's failing with authentication error "TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection" even I am passing /login parameter.

Once we enable interactive login and login use tf.exe workspaces command, it prompts for login once. after that builds started working fine. once we disabled interactive login on service account TF30063 error appeard again.

tf.exe works fine under service account if we run against on-premise TFS server, this only happens with VSTS.

any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the command `tf workspaces /collection:url /login:username,password` execute in TeamCity can checkin to TFS successful, but failed to checkin to VSTS?

Comment: Hi Daniel

Yes that's right. It works on tfs but fails on VSTS.
There is another difference, I am not passing /login param as service account has access to tfs.  VSTS is non federated so can't give service accou t access hence using alternative credentials under my login.

Thanks

Comment: You can use alternate credential or PAT with the option  `/login:##LIVE##\%username%,%password%` or `/login:##LIVE##\,%PAT%`. If you still fail to access, you can repoet the issue in teamcity (like https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203363090-TeamCity-cannt-connect-to-VSTS).

Comment: Hi @MarinaLiu-MSFT, I don't think this issue is related to teamcity as teamcity VCS roots for VSTS working fine with ##LIVE## format. Issue is related to tf.exe when I am using it in custom step through command line runner type.